# Scrolling over input tag cause a ‘sticky’ scrolling

Tags: ios, css, iphone, html, scroll

**UPDATE FOR SOLVE:
I'm using bootstrap and it has col classes. col class has position:relative property. In my case col classes depeneds a div which has not any position css property. So when I overrided col class position property:relative with position:inherit, my problem has solved**

I have a web page has some input elements at the end.

When I open it in IPhone version (5,5s,6,6s) I come over these input elements I got a sticky scrolling.

I'm not sure if I used the right expression but I mean I can not scroll more over up or down.

[image]

I'm using HTML5

Comment: a jsfiddle demo would be ideal